# Tag inside of beautifulsoup not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

this code does not print the list of companies as reqiured.
It does not reach inside first tag 
If i write "print 'text' " inside first tag it does not print it.
BeautifulSoup is working for a different code written for different sites.
Any suggestion why is it not working?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
request = urllib.urlopen('http://www.stockmarketsreview.com/companies_sp500/')
html = request.read()
request.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for tags in soup.find_all('div', {'class':'mainContent'}):
    for row in tags.find_all('tr'):
        for column in row.find_all('td'):
            print column.text
```

Comment: This code works for me..

Comment: maybe check your indentation in your actual code. What do you get when you run this, exactly?

Comment: Are you using `lxml` as the parser? Some versions of lxml, with some versions of the underlying libxml have real trouble with parsing some HTML.

Comment: In other words, does `BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')` make it work? If so, then you probably need to fix your `lxml` installation.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters I am not using lxml. Does need to be installed to run this code?

Comment: @KD_MOE: no, but if you did have it installed that'd have been a possible cause of the problems you appear to have. It is used automatically if you do have it installed, which is why I asked you to see if using `'html.parser'` explicitly (the default if `lxml` is not installed) makes a difference for you.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: thanks martijn, BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser') solved my problem. I had lxml but i was unable to find whether it was installed on my system.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Beautiful Soup 4 find\_all don't find links that Beautiful Soup 3 finds](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17698836/beautiful-soup-4-find-all-dont-find-links-that-beautiful-soup-3-finds)

Answer (score 0):

I have BeautifulSoup 3 and this seems to work correctly:

```
import BeautifulSoup as BS
import urllib
request = urllib.urlopen('http://www.stockmarketsreview.com/companies_sp500/')
html = request.read()
request.close()
soup = BS.BeautifulSoup(html)

try:
   tags = soup.findAll('div', attrs={'class':'mainContent'})
   print '# tags = ' + str(len(tags))
   for tag in tags:
      try:         
         tables = tag.findAll('table')
         print '# tables = ' + str(len(tables))
         for table in tables:            
            try:
               rows = tag.findAll('tr')
               for row in rows:
                  try:
                     columns = row.findAll('td')
                     for column in columns:
                        print column.text
                  except:
                     e = 1
                  #   print 'Caught error getting td tag under ' + str(row)
                  # This is okay since some rows have <th>, not <td>
            except:
               print 'Caught error getting tr tag under ' + str(table)
      except:
         print 'Caught error getting table tag under ' + str(tag)
except:
   print 'Caught error getting div tag'
```

I believe you'd need to replace 'findAll' with 'find_all'.

Output looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I used your code but it prints '# tags = 0'. I think i might have something not installed on my system to use this code for this site. But I have used such type of code for others sites. Any suggestion what i need to install to run this code

Comment: Perhaps BS4 is more different from 3.2.1 than I thought...  I added a pic of the output from the script when I run it.  I see '# tags = 1' followed by the listing of companies you're interested in parsing out.