# Python-BeautifulSoup4 Error: Some tags are getting removed after parsing

Tags: python, django, beautifulsoup

I am using [BeautifulSoup4](http://omz-software.com/pythonista/docs/ios/beautifulsoup_ref.html) for parsing the html content from a URL. But it seems that after the parsing some tags are removed from the actual html content. Please check my codes below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

site = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.shazam.com/charts/usa_top_100')
html_content = site.read()             #Check actual HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content)     #Compare the result with that one in previous step.
track_tags = soup.find_all('article')  #Returns an empty list for '<article>' tags evenif it exists in html content.
```

My requirement is to parse all 'article' tags and its content from the URL.

Thanks

Comment: Why removed, if I try the code I get 102 entries for "article" which is the correct number of article tags.

Comment: Do you have `lxml` installed perhaps?

Comment: I tested with all 3 supported parsers and all 3 return 102 results. Most likely you have a broken `lxml` setup, see [Beautiful Soup 4 find\_all don't find links that Beautiful Soup 3 finds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17698836)

Comment: The work-around would be to upgrade `lxml` and its dependencies, or to use a different parser backend; `BeautifulSoup(html_content, 'html.parser')` for example.

Comment: Yeah, something might went wrong with my bs4 implementation and worked fine with version 3. Great Thanks to all.