# beautifulsoup and invalid html document

Tags: python, html, parsing, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am trying to parse the document http://www.consilium.europa.eu/uedocs/cms_data/docs/pressdata/en/ecofin/acf8e.htm.
I want to get countries and names at the beginning of the document.

Here is my code

```
import urllib
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url="http://www.consilium.europa.eu/uedocs/cms_data/docs/pressdata/en/ecofin/acf8e.htm"
soup=BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url))
attendances_table=soup.find("table", {"width":850})
print attendances_table #this works, I see the whole table
print attendances_table.find_all("tr")
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'next_element'
```

I then tried to use the same solution as in this post (I know, again, me :p) :
[beautifulsoup with an invalid html document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23347376/beautifulsoup-with-an-invalid-html-document)

I replaced the line:

```
soup=BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url))
```

with:

```
return BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
```

Now if I do:

```
print attendances_table
```

I only get:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="850">
<tr><td valign="TOP" width="42%">
<p><b><u>Belgium</u></b></p></td></tr></table>
```

What should I change?

Comment: Different parsers parse it differently. `lxml` works fine for me, as does `html5lib`.

Comment: `html5lib` didn't work but `lxml` seems to work. Thanks again ;). Solved

Comment: Yes, there appears to be a bug in the way the `html5lib` tree builder creates the tree, and there is a dangling link in it (`None` instead of the next element).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Solved!

I just used another parser library, `lxml`.
Thank you Martijn Pieters for that!

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url), 'lxml')
```

`lxml` was the only library that worked for me!

Answer (score 10):

Use [`html5lib`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) as a parser, it is extremely lenient:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url), 'html5lib')
```

You would also need to install `html5lib` module first.

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib
>>> url = "http://www.consilium.europa.eu/uedocs/cms_data/docs/pressdata/en/ecofin/acf8e.htm"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.urlopen(url), 'html5lib')
>>> attendances_table = soup.find("table", {"width": 850})
>>> print attendances_table
<table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0" width="850">
<tbody><tr><td valign="TOP" width="42%">
<p><b><u>Belgium</u></b>:</p>
<p>Mr Philippe MAYSTADT</p></td>
<td valign="TOP" width="58%">
<p>Deputy Prime Minister, Minister for Finance and Foreign Trade</p></td>
</tr>
...
<tr><td valign="TOP" width="42%">
<b><u></u></b><u></u><p><u><b>Portugal</b></u>:</p>
<p>Mr António de SOUSA FRANCO</p>
<p>Mr Fernando TEIXEIRA dos SANTOS</p></td>
<td valign="TOP" width="58%">
<p>Minister for Finance</p>
<p>State Secretary for the Treasury and Finance</p></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

Workaround to make `find_all('tr')` work:

```
>>> attendances_table = BeautifulSoup(str(attendances_table), 'html5lib')
>>> print attendances_table.find_all("tr")
[<tr><td valign="TOP" width="42%">
<p><b><u>Belgium</u></b>:</p>
<p>Mr Philippe MAYSTADT</p></td>
...
<tr><td valign="TOP" width="42%">
<b><u></u></b><u></u><p><u><b>Portugal</b></u>:</p>
<p>Mr AntÃ³nio de SOUSA FRANCO</p>
<p>Mr Fernando TEIXEIRA dos SANTOS</p></td>
<td valign="TOP" width="58%">
<p>Minister for Finance</p>
<p>State Secretary for the Treasury and Finance</p></td>
</tr>]
```

Comment: I just tried html5lib. `print attendances_table` works but not `print attendances_table.find_all("tr")`. Does it work for you?

Comment: @rom: interesting, I can indeed reproduce your problem!

Comment: @rom yup, same here, let me see.

Comment: @rom I've posted a workaround, making `BeautifulSoup` parse it again helps. Doesn't look neat and beautiful but works. Try it.

Comment: Interesting solution but actually Martijn gave me a better idea: use the lxml library. It works so far :). Thanks anyway ;).