# BeautifulSoup lxml parser closing tags where it shouldn't be

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup's lxml parser to parse some html. However, it's not being parsed as it's written. For instance, the following code:

```
import bs4

my_html = '''
<html>
<body>
<B>
<P>
Hello, I am some bolded text
</P>
</B>
</body>
</html>
'''

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(my_html, 'lxml')
print soup.prettify()
```

will print:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <b>
  </b>
  <p>
   Hello, I am some bolded text
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

You can see that somehow the `<B>` tag from `my_html` gets closed off before the `<p>` tag in the prettified version, even though it should be closed off after the `</p>`. Any ideas about what might be going on? I'm totally baffled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you can't have a `<p>` tag inside of a `<b>` tag, so the parser is trying to fix broken HTML. Using html5lib's `html5lib` parser or Python's `html.parser` will result in your expected output (I only know this because I just tested it).

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into those, although I've had some other issues with the `html.parser` before at least.

Answer (score 2):

That's because paragraphs are not allowed inside the `<b>` tag.

Only tags that accept flow content are allowed as the parent of [`<p>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) tags. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) for a list.

However, you can do the reverse; `<p>` is allowed as the parent for `<b>` tags. In your case, your can change your raw HTML to something like this:

```
my_html = '''
<html>
<body>
<p>
<b>
Hello, I am some bolded text
</b>
</p>
</body>
</html>
'''
```

Comment: Thanks, although this is a file that I'm scraping, so I'd like to be able to handle this case since I don't really have control over what the document will look like.

Comment: @George: In that case, `html5lib` seems like your best bet, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23394822/2741678). It does work as expected for your case.