# beautiful soup and requests not getting full page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My code looks like this.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r  = requests.get("http://www.data.com.sg/iCurrentLaunch.jsp")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
n = soup.findAll('table')[7].findAll('table')
for tab in n:
    print tab.findAll('td')[1].text
```

what I am getting is the property name till IDYLLIC SUITES,after that I get error "list index out of range".What is the problem?

Comment: Do you have lxml installed? I cannot reproduce your problem with any of the 3 supported parsers, but some installations of lxml and dependencies have problems.

Comment: Yes,I have lxml installed

Comment: Does `BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')` work for you then?

Comment: Also see [Beautiful Soup 4 find\_all don't find links that Beautiful Soup 3 finds](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17698836)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what is exactly bothering you. Because when I tried your code (as it is) it worked for me.

Still, try changing the parser, may be to html5lib

So do,

pip install html5lib

And then change your code to,

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r  = requests.get("http://www.data.com.sg/iCurrentLaunch.jsp")
data = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data,'html5lib') # Change of Parser
n = soup.findAll('table')[7].findAll('table')
for tab in n:
    print tab.findAll('td')[1].text
```

Let me know if it helps

Comment: The output is the same for all three parsers.

Comment: Changing the parser worked for me.Thanks

Comment: I don't know whats the problem I tried lxml parser It gave the error of "list out of index"