# BeautifulSoup behaves differently on Amazon EC2 machine

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-ec2, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm running the following script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2
import sys

print sys.version

url = 'https://www.google.com/finance'
page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

trends_tag = soup.find('div', {'id': 'topmovers'})

tags = trends_tag.find_all('td', 'change chg')
print len(tags)

tag = tags[0]
print 'Tag: ' + tag.text
```

On my computer, the output is:

```
2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
11
Tag: 33.24%
```

On the EC2 machine, the output is:

```
2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]
11
Tag: 33.24%
12.18B


CLX

The Clorox Co
7.35%
11.67B


THOR

Thoratec Corporation
6.12%
1.47B


FOE

Ferro Corporation
6.03%
1.17B


NORD

Nord Anglia Education Inc
5.88%
1.70B


LosersChange
Mkt Cap



CRR

CARBO Ceramics Inc.
-16.10%
1.95B


CMCT

CIM Commercial Trust Corp
-10.54%
1.84B


HLF

Herbalife Ltd.
-10.31%
4.11B


INVN

InvenSense Inc
-10.10%
2.08B


TRS

TriMas Corp
-9.99%
1.34B
```

I've updated both machines to the same python version. The installed packages are a bit different though. My machine:

```
>pip freeze
PIL==1.1.7
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
colorama==0.3.1
cssselect==0.9.1
frida==1.6.0
lxml==3.4.0
newspaper==0.0.7
numpy==1.8.1
pefile==1.2.10-139
pudb==2013.5.1
pygments==1.6
requests==2.4.1
scikit-learn==0.15-git
urwid==1.2.0
xlrd==0.9.2
xlwt==0.7.5
```

The EC2 machine:

```
>pip freeze
beautifulsoup4==4.3.2
```

It seems that the find_all returns a tag much bigger than what it should be. Also, when running `print tags[0]` I get:

My machine:

```
<td class="change chg">33.24%
</td>
```

On the EC2 Machine:

```
<td class="change chg">33.24%
<td class="mktCap">12.18B
<tr>
<td class="symbol">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:CLX&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA" title="CLX">CLX</a>
<td class="name">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:CLX&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA">The Clorox Co</a>
<td class="change chg">7.35%
<td class="mktCap">11.67B
<tr>
<td class="symbol">
<a href="/finance?q=NASDAQ:THOR&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA" title="THOR">THOR
</a>
<td class="name">
<a href="/finance?q=NASDAQ:THOR&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA">Thoratec Corporat
ion</a>
<td class="change chg">6.12%
<td class="mktCap">1.47B
<tr>
<td class="symbol">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:FOE&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA" title="FOE">FOE</a>
<td class="name">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:FOE&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA">Ferro Corporation</a
>
<td class="change chg">6.03%
<td class="mktCap">1.17B
<tr>
<td class="symbol">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:NORD&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA" title="NORD">NORD</
a>
<td class="name">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:NORD&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA">Nord Anglia Educati
on Inc</a>
<td class="change chg">5.88%
<td class="mktCap">1.70B
<tr><td style="height:.7em">
<tr class="colHeader">
<td class="title chr">Losers<td class="change">Change
<td class="mktCap">Mkt Cap
</td></td></td></tr>
<tr>
<td class="symbol">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:CRR&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA" title="CRR">CRR</a>
<td class="name">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:CRR&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA">CARBO Ceramics Inc.<
/a>
<td class="change chr">-16.10%
<td class="mktCap">1.95B
<tr>
<td class="symbol">
<a href="/finance?q=NASDAQ:CMCT&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA" title="CMCT">CMCT
</a>
<td class="name">
<a href="/finance?q=NASDAQ:CMCT&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA">CIM Commercial Tr
ust Corp</a>
<td class="change chr">-10.54%
<td class="mktCap">1.84B
<tr>
<td class="symbol">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:HLF&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA" title="HLF">HLF</a>
<td class="name">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:HLF&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA">Herbalife Ltd.</a>
<td class="change chr">-10.31%
<td class="mktCap">4.11B
<tr>
<td class="symbol">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:INVN&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA" title="INVN">INVN</
a>
<td class="name">
<a href="/finance?q=NYSE:INVN&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA">InvenSense Inc</a>
<td class="change chr">-10.10%
<td class="mktCap">2.08B
<tr>
<td class="symbol">
<a href="/finance?q=NASDAQ:TRS&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA" title="TRS">TRS</a
>
<td class="name">
<a href="/finance?q=NASDAQ:TRS&amp;ei=lkwhVJDfJKjeiALmvYHACA">TriMas Corp</a>
<td class="change chr">-9.99%
<td class="mktCap">1.34B
<tr><td style="height:.7em">
</td></tr></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td>
</tr></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></tr></td></tr></td></td></td>
</td></tr></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td></tr></td></td></td></td>
</tr></td></td>
```

Notice the `</td></tr>` at the end - Like it merges the branches for some reason.

What can cause such a difference?

Sorry for the long question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is `lxml`. BeautifulSoup uses `lxml` as the default parser when installed, with a fallback to the standard library `HTMLParser` module when it is not.

Your input HTML is malformed, and parsers are allowed to 'make the best of it' when presented with such HTML. `lxml` and `HTMLParser` use different approaches to how to repair the HTML.

You can force BeautifulSoup to use a specific parser by naming it in a second argument when creating the `BeautifulSoup()` instance, see [*Specifying a parser to use*](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use):

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: I've installed lxml 3.4.0 (the same version as in my dev pc), and the problem persists. Is there another dependency?

Comment: @Nitay: triple check the data you receive is the same (md5 hash the strings to be certain perhaps). `lxml` uses `libxml2` which *may* be broken on certain platforms, see [Beautiful Soup 4 find\_all don't find links that Beautiful Soup 3 finds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17699341)

Comment: @Nitay: you can also install `html5lib` and use that parser with ` BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')`, it'll be slower but more predictable as to how it'll parse broken HTML.

Comment: Sorry - You're right. I've installed the 64bit instead of the 32bit. Reinstalling lxml 32 bits did the trick. Thanks!